# In yaml how to declare multiple value to the single key in tags

Tags: yaml, datadog

For e.g.
tags:

```
  - name:instancename
  - component:['component1','component2']
  - environment:uat
  - region:region
```

When using above syntax not getting logs in Datadog for component2 only getting logs only for component1 so we want to parse logs for both the component i.e component1 and component2 so how would get it?

Comment: From where are you getting this syntax? Looks like you are confusing what a [mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//) is and what a [sequence](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#sequence//) is

Comment: There is no such thing as „yaml scripting“. YAML is a data format without any scripting capabilities. You do need to tell us where you get the above syntax from, as the only YAML thing about it is that it is a block sequence – however, the colons are not parsed by YAML to separate key-value pairs as there is no whitespace behind them. A quick look at datadog docs did not show any indication that the syntax `:[a,b]` would work there either, and they actually have an open issue for [supporting multiple values for a tag](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1432).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datadog Tags are generally strings, but also support "key:value" strings, which is most useful, since then the `key` can act as a dimension.

There's no support that I know of that allows for a single key with multiple values, so I don't think Datadog will support the syntax you're attempting.

You *may* want to try:

```
...
  - component:component1
  - component:component2
...
```

in your config.

General reference here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/tagging/